# Angular promise callbacks and the digest cycle

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, angularjs-digest

Are promise callbacks in AngularJS guaranteed to be invoked in a digest cycle?

```
setTimeout(function () {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  deferred.resolve();
  deferred.promise.then(function () {
    if ($rootScope.$$phase) {
      //I seem to be hitting this block
      console.log("in digest");
    } else {
      //Could I ever hit this block?
      console.log("not in digest");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I was under the impression that the $digest cycle was Angular's own event loop, meaning that _everything_ executes in the $digest cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Short Answer

Yes*

#### *Long Answer

The provider for `$q` defines the [`nextTick` callback](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.8/src/ng/q.js#L219-L226) to call [`$rootScope.evalAsync(callback)`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$evalAsync).

Quoting from the manual:

> The $evalAsync makes no guarantees as to when the expression will be executed, only that:
>
> - it will execute after the function that scheduled the evaluation (preferably before DOM rendering).
> - at least one $digest cycle will be performed after expression execution.
>
> Any exceptions from the execution of the expression are forwarded to the $exceptionHandler service.
>
> **Note:** if this function is called outside of a $digest cycle, a new $digest cycle will be scheduled. However, it is encouraged to always call code that changes the model from within an $apply call. That includes code evaluated via $evalAsync.

Answer (score 0):

since i can not comment yet: yes, as long as you use `$q` to create your promise. using 3rd-party-promise-libraries you might be able to escape the digest loop.

btw you could write your code more elegant with a little hack:

```
$q.when([]).then(function(){
  ...
});
```